# Cannot Spool in Oracle 11g in docker from Mac, Issues of Filepath or Permission? (SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file)

Tags: oracle, macos, docker, sqlplus, filepath

I installed Oracle 11g xe on my Mac in docker:

```
docker run -h "oraclehost" --name "oracle" -d -p 1521:1521 carloscastillo/rgt-oracle-xe-11g
```

In docker terminal (CLI, not the normal Mac terminal), everything seems fine and I can execute queries:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Kevins-MacBook-Pro:~ kevin$ docker exec -it 6b............1a /bin/sh; exit
# sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mon Mar 15 10:50:29 2021
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter user-name: system
Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> connect hr/tiger
Connected.
```

But when I want to create spool files it shows the error bellow. I tried to google it but that still didn't work. Is the filepath correct? or does this action have the permission to do so?

```
SQL> SPOOL Users/kevin/Desktop/DBM/DBsession1.txt
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "Users/kevin/Desktop/DBM/DBsession1.txt"
```

Another question is that when I want to move arrow keys in the terminal in docker, it shows:
^[[C^[[C^[[D^[[C

I changed Mac terminal preference to Commanded (complete path): /bin/bash
as said in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384040/why-does-the-terminal-show-a-b-c-d-when-pressing-the-arrow-k), but that still does not work...

Can anyone help please leave a message, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Your scenario**

```
SQL> !df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          59G   40G   16G  72% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
overlay         3.0G  560K  3.0G   1% /usr/sbin/docker-init
/dev/vda1        59G   40G   16G  72% /etc/hosts
grpcfuse        932G  484G  431G  53% /opt/oracle/oradata
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/firmware

SQL>

SQL> spool /Users/BJBRA/Desktop/myfile.txt
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "/Users/BJBRA/Desktop/myfile.txt"
```

**What did I do?**

```
SQL> !df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay          59G   40G   17G  71% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
overlay         3.0G  560K  3.0G   1% /usr/sbin/docker-init
grpcfuse        932G  484G  431G  53% /desktop    <---------- HERE it is!
/dev/vda1        59G   40G   17G  71% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/firmware

SQL> spool /desktop/myfile.txt
SQL> select dummy from dual;

D
-
X

SQL> spool off
SQL> !cat /desktop/myfile.txt
SQL> select dummy from dual;

D
-
X

SQL> spool off
```

**Solution**

In order for you container to access a folder on your host-machine, you need to bind mount the host directory using the *-v* option

```
docker run -h "oraclehost" --name "oracle" -v /Users/kevin/Desktop/DBM:/DBM -d -p 1521:1521 carloscastillo/rgt-oracle-xe-11g
```

**sqlplus and arrow keys**

The tool rlwrap is needed in order for the arrow keys to work. Personally, I never operate a database from inside a container. I always use sqlplus installed on my Mac to access a container database - where I already have rlwrap installed by brew.

Install sqlplus on MacOS (download binaries from oracle.com)

```
# install on MacOS
brew tap InstantClientTap/instantclient
cp ~/Download/instantclient*.zip /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/instantclienttap/homebrew-instantclient
brew install instantclient-basic
brew install instantclient-sqlplus
brew install instantclient-tools

brew install rlwrap
Warning: rlwrap 0.45 is already installed and up-to-date.

alias sqlplus
alias sqlplus='rlwrap sqlplus'
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Many thanks for the details! But when I process the "-v" solution, it reads the container name "/oracle" is already in use by container "6b...". Should I remove the container "oracle" and all its data? And to re-bind again?

Comment: Since you haven't established an area for your datafiles outside the container, your datafiles (aka database) will be gone once you run 'docker container rm oracle'. If there isn't any valuable data in your database, then the answer is 'yes' and you can remove the container.