# Terminal in VS Code won't correctly show last command

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am currently using Visual Studio Code for my local development. I use the terminal for commands but have realized it will sometimes input something like `^[[A` instead of the last command I ran when I hit the up button. This is occurring on Bash and my zsh terminal. I am using a Mac as well. Is there any further configuration I need to do in order to show my last command and not this weird symbol that keeps showing up?

[The command shows up like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRSMT.png)

Comment: Try wiping the red marker off your computer screen.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think this solution helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347121/19633998

Basically all boils down to what sort of configuration your terminal has. Mine was defaulted to bin/zsh. Changed it to bin/bash and it seems to be working at the moment.